# Best Practice: Resharper warnings - Should they all be resolved?

Tags: resharper

The question: Should I take the time to fix Resharper warnings?  For example, The Namespace does not match the file location.  I have a hundred of these in a fairly large project.  It's going to take some time to resolve.

I know this question is a bit subjective, but in general, I have been ignorning these and many other warnings, but now I am thinking I should spend some time resolving these.

What is the best practice here?  My experience in a corporate environment is that if it's not a compile error, it gets ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to this ["inspection"](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/04/webinar-recording-jon-skeet-inspects-resharper/) by Jon Skeet on Resharper.

It will give you a good idea of what Resharper can do, and what resharper just cant do.

But the conclusion is, often, what resharper says is true. Not in EVERY case, but mostly. 
So yes, I would advise you to listen to Resharper. Its a bit of a brain itself.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like sage advice.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not all of them, but a lot of them are meaningful.

Also, there are many warnings that come from naming conventions and stuff that should be personal to your team, so if fixing a warning goes against your team's standard, I wouldn't fix it.

About that, you can change the options so Resharper doesn't warn you about naming (or better you could make your own naming conventions)

And personally, about the namespace thing, I usually place things at the right places, just so everyone finds what they're looking for easily.